# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...site-packages/testpath-0.3.1.dist-info/top_level.txt

Tags: python, kaggle

After I installed kaggle-cli, I did this on command line.

```
kg config
```

However, I got this error below.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/testpath-0.3.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
```

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: kaggle-cli doesn't involve testpath, but I can reproduce such issue with pyenv installed Python 3.6.0. Try to use anaconda3-4.4.0.

Comment: See https://github.com/floydwch/kaggle-cli/issues/48 .

Answer (score 1):

I used `pip3` to install the `kaggle-cli` (`pip3 install kaggle-cli`) and I got the same error. Then I uninstalled it and used `pip install kaggle-cli`, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed this down to an error in the 'cliff' module. I simply commented out some unnecessary code and it works fine.

Go to /site-packages/cliff/command.py and comment out lines 135-143. 
(everything after `parts.extend(hook_epilogs)` and before `return '\n\n'.join(parts)`)